# How to get captions over images in a responsive grid?

Tags: css, image, html, responsive-design

I have a responsive image grid and I want to have captions over the images. By using `position:absolute` and `bottom:0` for the `.title` divs (caption divs) I got the captions over the images, but I can't get the width of them to be the same as the width of the images - and to be responsive. Setting `width:100%` I get them wider than the images.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="grid">
  <li>
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="sampleimg.jpg">
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Image Title</h3>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.photo {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.photo img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.title {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #2c3f52;
    color: #ed4e6e;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.photo, .photo * {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.title {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #2c3f52;
    color: #ed4e6e;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts on how to accomplish this with Rails, and have it be dynamic?